# Can I use one power supply for different ampere motors? Will it affect the motors?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, current, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-motor

I have two motors, one motor uses 12 V 5 amps and another motor needs 12 V 7 amps, I have a power supply (SMPS) of 12 V 30 amp capacity. I'm planning to connect both motors to the same power supply. Will the motors be affected? When the 7 amp motor is consuming all 7 amps, will it affect the 5 amp motor?

Comment: "one motor uses 12 V 5 amps and another motor needs 12 V 7 amps"  Is that the motor's specified current draw, or is that what you've guaranteed with your circuitry or mechanical design?  If a motor is advertised as "5A" that usually means that it will work forever if _you design the mechanical load_ so the motor draws no more than 5A.  If you stall a "5A" motor it may draw many times more current than that.  A motor can stand that for short periods of time, but not for extended duration.

Comment: You should look into the datasheets of the motors for the start current when a not rotating motor is connected to 12V.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this will work fine. Connect all three devices in parallel. The power supply will keep the voltage at 12 volts no matter how many amps are drawn - as long as it's not overloaded - which it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

If these are brushed DC motors that are simply connected to the power supply with a switch, there is a good possibility that just the smaller motor alone will cause the power supply to shut off because of the inrush current.